# When your furniture are damaged at the time of replacement

Tags: verbs

How shall I describe this happening using the proper verb:

> - When we were moving to the new house the workes who were carrying the furniture were really careless and they.................the dresser's side OR the dresser's side was................

Which one of the folloing verbs normally are used here and in this sense:

> a) grinded - was grounded 
>   b) scratched - was scratched

I need to know the better choice if these words don't sound idiomatic to you.[image]

Comment: How about "scraped - was scraped"?

Comment: Why not just use *damaged* as you did in the title of your question? That's the most idiomatic verb here. When talking about movers, the general *damaged* is probably used far more often than any other specific verb. (*Broken* would also be very common—but wouldn't apply in the specific context of this question.)

Comment: Yes! You're right! It's probabely the most common word for this situation, but @Jason Bassford, actually I was looking for sth more more spesific than "to damage sth" and "to be damaged" in my question. However, thank you very much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Grinding** usually assumes that a special tool is used, and there is an intention to that action.

Note: The participle for "to grind" is "ground", not "grounded". "Grounded" is the participle from "to ground".

Therefore, **"to scratch / was scratched"** is the better alternative.

Another suitable word is **"to scrape / was scraped"**.

---

However, the shape of the damage dictates the correct word.

If the shape is a pattern of lines, then the proper word is **scratch**.

If the shape is an indefinite bruise, then the proper word is **scraped**.

The analysis of the picture provided gets us to the conclusion that **scratch**  is the proper word in this situation. Lines are clearly visible.

---

Please see this [question and answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/207984/89027) for some additional pictures, applied to a different context.

---

According to the discussion on [this page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/77513/89027) (not much voted yet), the correct way to say is:

> the furniture **is**

instead of

> the furniture **are**